# resetting an angular form after it has been submitted

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

I have an angular form (not reactive).It has some required fields which get highlighted in red if empty during submission of the form. Now if I submit the form and then empty the required fields, still the fields get highlighted(even though the form is not submitted again) . Is there a way to not show this validation until the form is submitted again?

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && moveAsset()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
      <button type="submit" id="MoveAsset" name="MoveAsset" tabindex="214"
                        class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" 
                        [disabled]="assetMoveFieldAccessData['Move']">
                        {{fields['Move']}}
      </button>
      <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="col-form-label control-label col-sm-4 for="site">
           {{fields['Site']}}
          </label>
          <ng-select ngSelectSetTabindex [items]="siteList" name="siteid" id="siteid" tabindex="204" 
            (change)="siteChange()" bindLabel="siteName" bindValue="siteId" [(ngModel)]="site" 
            #siteid="ngModel" required  placeholder="{{fields['Select Site']}}"
            [ngClass]="{ 'invalid-errors-br': (f.submitted && (site == 0|| site == null || site == 
            undefined))}" >
          </ng-select>
      </div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
myform: FormGroup;
@ViewChild('f', {static: true}) myForm;
public moveAsset(){
      this.myForm.reset();
     }
```

Comment: In your form, you just have a "select input" and there is no "text input"??

Comment: It'll be easier if you can provide a reproducible version on stackblitz.com